# vueChart.js child component not updating with data

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm creating a bar chart that displays data for crime in a particular location. You can choose the location using a select, this updates the longitude and latitude in the location fetch.

I loop through the data to create an object with type of crime and number of each crime per category. I then pass this data to the child component (bar chart) to display. However, when selecting a new location the data doesn't seem to pass down to the child component so the bar chart isn't displaying any data.

My code:
App.vue

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Crime Rates in {{selectedLocation}}</h1>
        <BarChartNew v-if="theData" :dataset="theData" :labels="labels" />
    
        <select name="location" @change="getLocation($event, this.locations)" v-model="selectedLocation">
          <option v-for="(coordinates, location) in locations" :key="location" :value="location">
            {{location}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { locations } from "@/middleware/locations.js";
    import BarChartNew from "./components/barChartNew.vue";
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: { BarChartNew },
      data() {
        return {
          crimes: null,
          locations,
          theData: [],
          labels: [],
          selectedLocation: 'Bristol',
          categoryObject: {}
        };
      },
      methods: {
        async fetchData(selectedLocation) {
          const lat = this.locations[selectedLocation].lat
          const lng = this.locations[selectedLocation].lng
    
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
              `https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}&date=2023-01`,
              {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain",
              }
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            const allCategories = data.map((item) => item.category);
    
            for (let item in data){
              this.categoryObject.hasOwnProperty(data[item].category) 
              ? this.categoryObject[data[item].category]++ 
              : this.categoryObject[data[item].category] = 1
            }
            this.labels.push(...Object.keys(this.categoryObject))
            this.theData = Object.values(this.categoryObject)
          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
          }
        },
        getLocation(event){
          const selectedLocation = event.target.value
    
          this.labels = [];
          this.fetchData(event.target.value)
    
    
          return { selectedLocation }
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.fetchData(this.selectedLocation);
      },
    }
    </script>
```

barChartNew.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <Bar
        :data="chartData"
        :options="chartOptions"
    />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'


ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  components: { Bar },
  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
    },
    labels: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            borderColor: "#f6b09e",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(246, 176, 157)",
            label: "crimes",
            data: this.dataset,
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
          legend: { display: true },
          title: { display: true, text: "Crimes  in your area" },
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please include your App.vue code as a snippet like you did barChartNew.vue? It's much more preferred than [using images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your `chartData` in the child component:

1. it is not updated when data changes
2. chart-js requires you to rebuild both the `chartData` object and the `chartData.datasets` array to detect changes and redraw the chart

You can fix both by turning your `chartData` into a computed property:

```
  computed: {
    chartData(){
      return {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            borderColor: "#f6b09e",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(246, 176, 157)",
            label: "crimes",
            data: this.dataset,
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a simplified [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)